# How to draw a 3D plane by using the function f(x,y,z)==0?

Tags: plotting

[image]

My attempt is below:

```
Plot3D[{3 x + 4 y + 5 z + 6 == 0}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, - 1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

What I want to draw is something like this!

[image]

Comment: try `ContourPlot3D`?

Comment: Thanks man @kglr

Comment: there is a , missing after the y

Comment: @chris, I got it, thanks man

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
     ContourPlot3D[
 3 x + 4 y + 5 z + 6 == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> {Opacity[0.3], Lighter[Purple, 0.1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Hyperplane](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hyperplane.html)

```
RegionMember[Hyperplane[{a, b, c}, -d], {x, y, z}]
```

> (x | y | z) ∈ Reals && a * x + b * y + c * z == -d

```
Graphics3D[Hyperplane[{3, 4, 5}, -6]]
```

[image]

Comment: First time know this function, really helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Lawrence 不客气，李海洋同学。

Answer (score 2):

`Plot3D` plots a function of the form $z = f(x,y)$, not a relation of the form $f(x,y,z) = 0$.  As other answers have noted, `ContourPlot3D` will do the latter.  But if you're committed to using `Plot3D`, here's how to do it:

```
zfunc = z /. First[Solve[3 x + 4 y + 5 z + 6 == 0, z]]
Plot3D[zfunc, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

The first line "solves for $z$" in the equations you have, and the second one plots the solution for $z = f(x,y)$.

Comment: The above code is untested, so leave a comment below if it doesn't work (or edit the above answer if you can see how to fix it.)

Comment: It works, really thanks